# Image not being uploaded .I want to upload the image and save it into the database i've given the media root and media url

Tags: python, django

applyonline.html(I have given file fields for adhaarcopy and idcopy)

```
<body ng-app="">
{% extends "pmmvyapp/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content%}
<div class="col-md-8">
  <form method="post" action="/personal_detail/">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class=" mb-4">
      <h6><u>(*Mandatory Fields)Please Fill up the details below </u></h6>
    </div>
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" ,align="center">1.Beneficiary Details</legend>
    <label for="formGropuNameInput">Does Beneficiary have an Adhaar Card?*</label>
    <input type="radio" name="showHideExample" ng-model="showHideTest" value="true">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="showHideExample" ng-model="showHideTest" value="false">No
   <!--logic for yes-->
    <div ng-if="showHideTest=='true'">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGropuNameInput">Name of Beneficiary(as in Aadhar Card)*</label>
        <input name="beneficiary_adhaar_name" class="form-control" id="formGroupNameInput" placeholder="Enter name of Beneficiary as in Aadhar Card" required>
      </div>       
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="adhaaarcopy">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--logic for no-->
    <div ng-if="showHideTest=='false'">     
      <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-group">
          <label for="adhaar_eid">Aadhaar Enrollment ID(EID):</label>
          <input name="adhaar_eid" id="identityno"  class="form-control" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">        
          <label for="formGropuNameInput">Name of Beneficiary(as in Identity Card)* </label>
          <input name="beneficiary_id_name" class="form-control" id="formGroupNameInput" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="idno">Identity Number(Enclose Copy of Identity Card)*:</label>

          <input name="idno" id="identityno"  class="form-control" required>
          </div>

       <div class="custom-file">

            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="idcopy" id="customFile">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px ">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>   
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

this is my views.py i've used POST.get

```
@login_required
def personal_detail(request):
   # ShowHideExample = request.POST.get('showHideExample',False)
    beneficiary_adhaar_name=request.POST.get('beneficiary_adhaar_name')
    adhaarno=request.POST.get('adhaarno')
    adhaarcopy=request.POST.get('adhaarcopy')

    idcard=request.POST.get('idcard')
    adhaar_eid=request.POST.get('adhaar_eid')   
    beneficiary_id_name=request.POST.get('beneficiary_id_name')
    idno=request.POST.get('idno')
    idcopy=request.POST.get('idcopy')
    apply_online = Personal_Detail(beneficiary_adhaar_name=beneficiary_adhaar_name,adhaarno=adhaarno,adhaarcopy=adhaarcopy,
    idcard=idcard,adhaar_eid=adhaar_eid,beneficiary_id_name=beneficiary_id_name,idno=idno,idcopy=idcopy)
    apply_online.save()
    return render(request,'users/applyonline.html')
```

this is my models.py where i have created FileField for both

```
class Personal_Detail(models.Model):
    beneficiary_adhaar_name=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    adhaarno=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    adhaarcopy = models.FileField(upload_to='adhaar/')


    idcard=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    adhaar_eid=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)    
    beneficiary_id_name=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    idno=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    idcopy=models.FileField(upload_to='identitycard/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.beneficiary_adhaar_name or self.beneficiary_id_name
```

settings.py I have given the media root and provided the media url

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK='bootstrap4'
```

Like I want to know how can I upload the images like what should be my next steps.

Comment: Why don't you use a `form` on Django side? Try implementing a trivial form and following the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

You should get the file after submitted the form as below...

```
idcopy = request.FILES['idcopy']
adhaaarcopy = request.FILES['adhaaarcopy']
```

insted of...

```
idcopy=request.POST.get('idcopy')
adhaaarcopy=request.POST.get('adhaaarcopy')
```

And so on for other fields...

After that you can save and get it in appropriate location in media.

Comment: but iam unable to get the file when I am clicking choose file and select the file/image nothing is happening

Comment: Are you applied any JS or CSS regarding to file input fields from HTML page?

Comment: Yes, That I know and its look good. But if you are used any js or css which are being used when load your form then you can add that js and css in question.

Comment: Are you checked the console of the browser after choosing any file?

Comment: no but right now i used   <input type="file" name="idcopy" />
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /> and in view request.FILES.get('idcopy') as I was getting MultivalueDictKeyError